# Cutsom user id for clients in my Wordpress webshop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Wordpress combined with Woocommerce for my company. When new clients want to order something, they have to create an account during the order.

I would like my new clients to have a custom user id. Instead of a number, I would like the ID of the client to be: the first 2 letters of their last name, the last 2 numbers of the year they have registered, the month they have registered, followed by his ID number.

For example:
Bob Clark registers today at my website as a client. Bob automatically gets user id 300. However, I want that the ID of bob becomes:

First 2 letters of his last name – last 2 numbers of the year – month – Bob his ID. Therefore, this will be:

CL1707300

Could someone help me out with this?

Current code:

```
    /* Add user "my_unique_id" meta when user register through checkout page woocommerce */
add_action('woocommerce_created_customer', 'admin_email_on_registration', 10 , 1);
function admin_email_on_registration($user_id) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $last_name =  $user->last_name; 
    if ( isset($last_name) ){
        //do your stuff
       $unique_id = mb_substr($last_name, 0, 2, 'utf-8') . date("y") . date("m") . $user_id;
       add_user_meta( $user_id, 'my_unique_id', $unique_id);
    }
}
```

update:

```
<tr class="Klantnummer">
    <th><?php _e( 'Klantnummer:'); ?></th>
    <td><?php echo $user->ID; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Could you provide some more information on what caused the crash?

Comment: With this code, the site did not crash, however it does not seem to do anything. But when I try to modify the code I let the site crash often due to syntax errors. I don't have (much) experience with Php, that's why. Thank you for the response.

Comment: It could be a variety of problems, if $user_id is stored as an INT in your database then you can't store string values there, also your concatenation might be wrong on this line `$unique_id = mb_substr($last_name, 0, 2) + date("Y") + date("m") + $user_id;` try replacing it with `mb_substr($last_name, 0, 2) . date("Y") . date("m") . $user_id;` `

Comment: I tried to replace the code with "mb_substr($last_name, 0, 2) . date("Y") . date("m") . $user_id;" , however this did not fix the problem. After the order is placed, the customer gets an in voice where his customer ID is printed. However, it still says "Customer ID: 10".

Comment: Hi - can I offer a word of advice.  What you seem to be doing here is updating your question based on answers and then asking more questions in comments.  That's not how it works here, you ask a question and then other users answer.  If you want to ask another question then do so but don't turn this into an ongoing debugging exercise. Mark the answer correct if it helped you. Your edit now means the answer doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace your code like this:

100% tested and working code..

```
/* Add user "my_unique_id" meta when user register through registration form */
add_action('user_register','my_on_user_register');
function my_on_user_register($user_id){
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    if ( isset($last_name) ){
        //do your stuff
       $unique_id = mb_substr($last_name, 0, 2, 'utf-8') . date("Y") . date("m") . $user_id;
       add_user_meta( $user_id, 'my_unique_id', $unique_id);
    }
}

/* Add user "my_unique_id" meta when user register through checkout page woocommerce */
add_action('woocommerce_created_customer', 'admin_email_on_registration', 10 , 1);
function admin_email_on_registration($user_id) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $last_name =  $user->last_name; 
    if ( isset($last_name) ){
        //do your stuff
       $unique_id = mb_substr($last_name, 0, 2, 'utf-8') . date("Y") . date("m") . $user_id;
       add_user_meta( $user_id, 'my_unique_id', $unique_id);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have replaced the code, however, it still is not working. Currently, the customer ID shown on the invoice is "11".

Comment: Sorry, I just did something wrong and I am not able to enter my DirectAdmin anymore. I will have to wait until my host fixes the problem. Thank you for the response, I will come back to your answer!

Comment: I updated my question with a screenshot of my wp_usermeta in my database. I cannot find "my_unique_id" anywhere. Maybe it because the way users are registered when placing an order in Woocommerce?

Comment: Thank you for the updated code. I tried it, however still no "my_unique_id" in my database, and thus not on the invoice. :(

Comment: I have shared the code. However, in the database there is no "my_unique_id", therefore the user_id cannot be overwritten right?

Comment: I have changed "$userInfo->last_name;" to "$user->last_name;" and now my database contains "my_unique_id".

However, it is missing the first 2 letters of the last name (170817 instead of CL170817). Also the invoice does not show the unique id.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last letters of the name no matter the language with `preg_match()` and a little bit of regex. I haven't benchmarked it but it may be faster than `mb_substr()` with some encodings. Also the dot `.` is used for string for concatenation in PHP not the "+".

```
// Add action hook for our. Note the last number, this indicates we
// intend to use the provided parameter.
add_action( 'user_register', 'so_add_custom_meta_on_registration', 10, 1 );

function so_add_custom_meta_on_registration( $user_id ) {

    if (isset($_POST['last_name'])) {
      $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
      // $matches[0] will contain the last two letters of the users last name
      preg_match('/\p{L}{2}$', $last_name, $matches);
      $lastname_letters = $matches[0];
      $year_numbers = date('y');
      $month_number = date('m');
      $unique_id = $lastname_letters . $year_numbers . $month_number . (string) $user_id;

      update_user_meta($user_id, 'my_unique_id', $unique_id);
    }
}
```

All the different variables were added for clarity, we could shorten that to:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'so_add_custom_meta_on_registration', 10, 1 );

function so_add_custom_meta_on_registration( $user_id ) {
    if (isset($_POST['last_name'])) {
      preg_match('/\p{L}{2}$', $_POST['last_name'], $matches);
      $unique_id = $matches[0] . date('y') . date('m') . (string) $user_id;

    update_user_meta($user_id, 'my_unique_id', $unique_id);
    }
}
```

**So how does it work?**

First we make sure the user is passing their last name to use in `$_POST['last_name']`

Next we use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) with a bit of regex to capture the last two letters from the user's last name and store it in the variable `$matches`. This variable is an array so we access the letters by getting the first (and only) element in the array with `$matches[0]`.

The regex we pass as the first parameter is `/\p{L}{2}$` where `\p{L}` matches any kind of letter from any language, `{2}` specifies we want 2 of those letters and `$` specifies we want them from the end. You can use [this online tool](https://regex101.com/) to test what your regex matches.

Next we use the `date()` function to give use our desired date numbers. [More info on the different formats here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Finally we add them all together using the `.`, or the concatenation operator.

Save it as user meta and we are ready to go!

Comment: Dear DaveLak,

Thank you for the explanation. I added the shortened code in my functions.php of my child-theme. However, after creating a new account when placing an order, the invoice still shows ID #12 instead of what I want. Also in my "wp_usermeta" in my database I cannot find "my_unique_id".

Do you have any clue? Maybe it is the way an account is registered by Woocommerce?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Honestly I didn't get a chance to test this code fully but I do think it should work. I'm working on a woocommerce project of my own a little later so I'll test it then and fix it if I need to. Also, to be clear, you are not changing the WP user ID itself; that would be a bad idea because too many things use it and expect it to be a number with no letters. Instead what you are doing is adding your custom ID as metadata (data about data) to the user. This way you have your custom ID and WP has it's regular ID.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in place of your code

```
 add_action('user_register','my_on_user_register');
function my_on_user_register($user_id){
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    if ( isset($last_name) ){
        //do your stuff
       $unique_id = mb_substr($last_name, 0, 2, 'utf-8') . date("Y") . date("m") . $user_id;
       add_user_meta( $user_id, 'my_unique_id', $unique_id);
    }
}
```